# Azure Resource Provider

Tags: azure

I registered Microsoft.Insights in Resource provider.
But, I don't know How do I register RegistrationPolicy.

How do I register RegistrationPolicy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need and cannot register `RegistrationPolicy`. This property is set by Microsoft and only for your information.  Your resource provider `microsoft.insights` is already registered and is ready to be used.  You can see this in RegistrationState-property having value Registered.

The preset value of policy can be either RegistrationRequired or RegistrationFree. You can get the full list of resource providers and their policies by listing all providers with command `az provider list -o table`. The RegistrationFree policy is for some core services in Azure infra that are preregistered, e.g Portal, Billing, support. You can get this list with command:

```
$ az provider list --query "[?registrationPolicy!='RegistrationRequired']" -o table
Namespace                        RegistrationState    RegistrationPolicy
-------------------------------  -------------------  --------------------
Microsoft.Portal                 Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Authorization          Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.ADHybridHealthService  Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Billing                Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.ClassicSubscription    Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Commerce               Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Consumption            Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.CostManagement         Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Features               Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.MarketplaceOrdering    Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.ResourceGraph          Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.Resources              Registered           RegistrationFree
Microsoft.SerialConsole          Registered           RegistrationFree
microsoft.support                Registered           RegistrationFree
```